# XMLReader parser error 0xC2 0xA0 0x20 0x2A

Tags: php, xml, encoding, utf-8, xmlreader

```
<?php       
$url = 'http://playroom.pl/hurtownia/xml/playroom_xml_1_0.xml';
$XMLReader = new XMLReader;
$XMLReader->open($url,'UTF-8');

while($XMLReader->read())
{
    switch($XMLReader->name) {
        case 'offer':
            break;      
        case 'param':
            $key = $XMLReader->getAttribute('name');
            $value = $XMLReader->readString();
            var_dump($key);
            var_dump($value);
            break;
        case '#cdata-section';
            $XMLReader->read();
            break;          
    }
}
```

> XMLReader::readInnerXml(): http://playroom.pl/hurtownia/xml/playroom_xml_1_0.xml:2: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
>   Bytes: 0xC2 0xA0 0xC2 0xA0

Crash at node with html string.
Large third party XML, file encoded UTF-8, declaration inside `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, test at validators - no errors. PHP Version 7.0.8-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1

0xC2,0xA0 is rather valid UTF-8 nonbreaking space.

How to parse it?

Comment: Does look like a bug in XMLreader. I can see that the XML file itself is well-formed XML, but you knew that already.